# Error "The label reference, Version, could not be found". when adding a Label to my Document site content type's "Information management settings"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning, information-management

I want to show the document versions inside our sharepoint online document libraries' items. so i follow these steps, which show how we can add a Label inside our document list content type:-

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chhopkin/2014/02/24/showing-the-document-version-number-on-a-visio-document/

and this worked well, where i was able to add the {Version} label to my document list content type. but since we have many document libraries, so i want to set the {Version} label on the Document site content type and not on the Document list content type. but when i try adding the {Version} label to my Document site content type i got this error :-

```
"The label reference, Version, could not be found"
```

so not sure why i can add the {Version} label to my list content type while i can not do the same for the site content type? as doing this on the site content type which will allow me to update all current and future lists at once..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced it.

Per my research, the reason should be there is no Version column in this site content type.

The Version column is part of the list and library. So that, we can use "{Version}" label for the list content type associated to the library or the list.

Comment: but if i edit all my Document list content types to add the `{Version}` labels, then i will loose the ability to apply any policy to the Document site content type is this correct? as let say in the future i want to define a retention policy for all my document libraries, and if i define the retention policy on the Document site content type, then it will override the Labels i defined on the Document list CT, and the Document list CT will no longer be editable on the list level.. so there are many drawback on modifying list CTs, as i will loose the ability to modify the CT at site level

Comment: so seems if i want to add `{Version}` i have to live with the above issue??

Comment: Yes. You need to modify the list content type.

Comment: but if i edit all my Document list content types to add the {Version} labels, then i will loose the ability to apply any global policy to the Document site content type is this correct? as let say in the future i want to define a retention policy for all my document libraries, and if i define the retention policy on the Document site content type, then it will override the Labels i defined on the Document list CT, and the Document list CT will no longer be editable on the list level..

Comment: ... so there are many drawback on modifying list CTs, as i will loose the ability to modify the CT at site level, as it will override the {Version} labels defined at the list CT.. so seems if i want to add {Version} i have to live with the above issue?? and there is not way to get around this limitation?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Some workarounds: https://blog.busitec.de/insert-sharepoint-version-number-in-a-word-document/

Comment: what a workaround :) i do not think i am going to do all these steps just to get the {Version}..